Strapi v5 user output sanitization
I've got a new project which I started with strapi v5 (5.4.1 at the moment).
In this I've got a custom controller for the current user as I want to query relations for the user as well. So I made a custom controller for the /api/user endpoint.
And here's where my question comes; when querying the /api/user endpoint, strapi takes the jwt sent with the request and finds the assciated user. It does not, however, sanitize the user data, i.e. the hashed password is included in the response. In strapi v4 you could sanitize a user object with something like this:
const user = await strapi.entityService.findOne('plugin::users-permissions.user', id, {
      populate: ['teams',],
    });

const schema = strapi.getModel('plugin::users-permissions.user');
return await utils.sanitize.contentAPI.output(user, schema);

which would then return the sanitized user object without the hashed password field. Unfortunately this method doesn't work anymore in v5. So my question would be: How do I sanitize the user object in strapi v5?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, greetz
DeM

You can try this:
import utils from '@strapi/utils'

const user = await strapi.entityService.findOne('plugin::users-permissions.user', id, {
  populate: ['teams'],
});

const schema = strapi.getModel('plugin::users-permissions.user');
return utils.sanitize.sanitizers.defaultSanitizeOutput({ schema, getModel: strapi.getModel }, user)



Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
